# Enable azure app service authentication and create app registration in azure cli

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-cli

So [this step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-authentication-app-service#:%7E:text=In%20the%20Azure%20portal%20menu,then%20click%20Add%20identity%20provider.) is nice and easy, one click and you're done.  How do I do this with the azure cli?  Do I need to create the app registration and then set the auth settings for the app service as seperate steps?  No one and done like the portal ui?

Answer (score 1):

Open the Command prompt and run the below commands to connect to `Azure CLI`.

```cs
az login
```

We can run either from Azure cloudshell or from Local Command Prompt.
If we want to add any files, then it is better to run from local so that providing the path will be easy.

***Enable Azure App Service Authentication***

Copy the Application Name for which you want to add `Authentication`.

Application `Authentication` before Enabling.

[image]

Run the below command to `Enable Authentication` for `Azure App Service`.

I have followed the [MSDoc - az webapp auth update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/webapp/auth?view=azure-cli-latest#az-webapp-auth-update) command to Enable Authentication.

```cs
az webapp auth update --resource-group MyRGName --name AzureAppServiceName --enabled true --action LoginWithAzureActiveDirectory
```

[image]

[image]

***Create app registration in AAD:***

I have followed the CLI Command from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/ad/app?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-create) to create a new App Registration in AAD.

```cs
az ad app create --display-name MyAppReg24Mar23
```

[image]

Here I have created an App without any parameters. We can update it later using the `az ad app update` command.

[image]

Comment: There should be more to it, no?

Comment: could you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908409/how-to-add-built-in-authentication-to-an-app-service-using-only-azure-cli?